# Is there a way to keep Visual Studio from modifying the solution file after every test run?

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio seems to be modifying a list of .vsmdi files in my .sln <strike>every time</strike> sometimes when I run a unit test. This is annoying because my source control client thinks the .sln file needs to be checked in even though I don't want to check it in. Is there any way to keep Visual Studio from munging the .sln file after a test run?

**Edit:** Found a Microsoft Connect [issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/Validation.aspx?FeedbackID=353784) discussing this, which sucks because things just sort of disappear from there after a little while and its a terrible bug tracker

Comment: Isn't it an option to beak the link to source control for .sln files after some initial setup? My experience is that they don't change really that often once the scope of a project is known, and you can get by with the occasional manual update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe a solution exists. A good Connect case, that does a better job of documenting the issue and a repro case, is [this one](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=350583). At the very bottom of the page a commenter proposes a workaround, which I've reproduced here. I haven't actually tested this workaround for myself yet, I guess I've gotten numb to discarding the changes caused by this bug :(

From the connect case:

> I have been able to repro this problem
>   by having developer A run tests with
>   the vsdmi file while developer B check
>   it out and adds unit tests to the
>   vsdmi. This typically will cause a new
>   one to be generated.
>
> The workaround that has worked for me
>   is to create vsdmi files per dev for
>   unit testing activities that are not
>   checked in to SCC and create special
>   vsdmis for build testing and automated
>   regression.
>
> Yuck, but it works.

Comment: Not sure I understand the workaround. Can anybody clarify this?

Comment: Luke: I'm not sure I understand it either, I just copied it from a Connect case that seems to contain a good writeup :)  No one on my team besides me runs the tests with any frequency, so it hasn't been worth my time to test any workarounds... I'm so used to this bug I hardly notice it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oops, was confused about the "list of vsmdi files" thing. Suggestion wouldn't have worked.

Comment: Yeah I kinda need to keep .sln files in source control

Answer (score 0):

That is a question for the ages...I always check if the solution has been checked out for whatever reason before I commit changes.